# CakePHP question: How can i upgrade a cakephp project from cakephp-1.3.10 to cakephp-1.3.11?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have developed a project with cakephp-1.3.10 .

Now I want to upgrade it to cakephp-1.3.11.

What's the easiest process to upgrade from cakephp-1.3.10 to cakephp-1.3.11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the cake zip, unpack, delete the app folder, put your app folder in.

Comment: No, the app folder of latest cakephp can be different .

Comment: @guru: I would check the announcement for this version: if there is nothing mentioned about the app folder it is usually good to proceed as described by Anh Pham. To be completely sure nothing changed, make a diff of the app folders of the two different versions.

Comment: if they change app folder structurally, it wouldn't be 1.3.11 (1.4, maybe). But yeah, before upgrading anything, always read the Changelog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can't use composer! And there's a high cost in upgrading by a large jump between versions, meaning that you will end up with a lot of deprecated code.

I would go like:

1. complete backup
2. upload your app to a Github repository
3. tag your code
4. create a new branch
5. upload your new code
6. debug
7. merge branch

Answer (score 0):

since you were just upgrading from 1.3.10 to 1.3.11 the simplest way would have been to download latest cakephp and then simply copy **lib/** folder from the downloaded folder and replacing it with your existing cakephp/lib/ folder. I would prefer to download latest version from cakephp's official website **https://cakephp.org/**

**Note-** If you have to upgrade from 1.x to 3.x then you have to move from 1.x to 2.x and then 2.x to 3.x, direct migration from 1.x to 3.x is not possible